# Match SQL Tables and find if entry exist in each group

Tags: sql, sql-server

Thanks for the response but if the scenario is extended up to add a third Group_ID with just 2 GroupNames only the it picks up that too .
Please help me in writing a query which will match 2 tables and find the group id in which all the entries of second table match.

**Table 1**

```
Group_Id   GroupNames     GroupValues    
111          G1              A    
111          G1              B    
111          G1              C    
111          G2              D    
111          G2              E    
111          G2              F    
111          G3              G    
222          G1              A    
222          G1              B    
222          G1              C    
222          G2              E    
222          G2              F    
222          G3              G
333          G3              G
333          G1              B
333          G1              C
```

**Table 2:**

```
GroupValues    
B    
D    
G
H
```

**OUTPUT**

```
111
```

The Output of the query should be "111" since it has atleast one entry for all three Group Names "G1,G2,G3" . "222" is missing entry for Group Name G2 so it will not be returned.
Please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select t1.Group_Id
from table1 t1 inner join
     table2
     on t2.GroupValues = t1.GroupValues
group by t1.Group_id
having count(distinct t1.GroupValues) = (select count(distinct GroupValues) from table2);
```

Note that the `distinct` is not necessary if you know there are no duplicate values.

Comment: This too worked  **select t1.Group_Id
from table1 t1 inner join
     table2 t2
     on t2.GroupValues = t1.GroupValues
group by t1.Group_id
having count(distinct t1.GroupValues) = (select count(distinct GroupValues) from table2);

Comment: @Piyush . . . I am unclear as to how the query in your comment differs from the one in my answer, except that you have qualified `GroupValues` in the `count(distinct)` (which is a good thing).

Comment: @Gordon...I meant your query worked too ...but GroupNames was not being considered in that.

Answer (score 0):

Posting two solutions, one is little modification to what Gordon Linoff suggested and another a new one.

1) The inline view T1 add , incase if you have duplicate GroupValues within a particular Group_ID

```
select t1.Group_Id
from (select distinct Group_Id,GroupValues from table1 )t1 inner join
     table2
     on t2.GroupValues = t1.GroupValues
group by t1.Group_id
having count(distinct GroupValues) = (select count(distinct GroupValues) from table2)
```

2) In the SELECT bellow minus , is used for identifying the Group_ID's which are not complete (or has all the combinations of group_id and GroupValues ). These id's are removed from all the group_id's present in the table1, hence the result.

```
select distinct group_id 
from table1
minus 
select distinct Group_Id
from Table2 t2,(select distinct Group_Id from Table1 ) t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from Table1 t11
                  where t1.Group_Id = t11.Group_Id
                    and t11.GroupValues = t2.GroupValues)
```